# Ember-cli : relationship unit test for model failing

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js, ember-data, qunit

I am using Ember-cli and qunit for testing.

Item Model

```
import DS from 'ember-data';
var attr = DS.attr,
    belongsTo = DS.belongsTo;

export default DS.Model.extend({
  offer: belongsTo('offer'),
});
```

Here am adding test for relation between item and Offer model.

Item Tests

```
import Ember from "ember";
import DS from "ember-data";
import { test, moduleForModel } from 'ember-qunit';

moduleForModel('item', 'Item Model', {
  needs: ['model:item']
});

test('offer relationship', function() {
  var relationships = Ember.get(App.Item, 'relationships');
  deepEqual(relationships.get(App.Offer), [
    { name: 'offer', kind: 'belongsTo' }
  ]);
});
```

Error Trace:

```
Died on test #1     at test (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73836:13)
    at eval (goodcity/tests/unit/item-test.js:44:5)
    at requireModule (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:54:29)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/test-loader.js:14:29: App is not defined
Source:     
ReferenceError: App is not defined
    at Object.eval (goodcity/tests/unit/item-test.js:45:37)
    at Object.wrapper (http://localhost:4200/assets/vendor.js:73824:31)
    at Object.Test.run (http://localhost:4200/assets/qunit.js:203:18)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/qunit.js:361:10
    at process (http://localhost:4200/assets/qunit.js:1453:24)
    at http://localhost:4200/assets/qunit.js:479:5
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm just now in the process of converting over an older Ember App to the new ember-cli and ran into a similar situation.  Since Ember CLI uses ES6 module syntax you can't access anything directly on the App object.

You will need to import your objects from their respective model files.

```
import Item from "<modulePrefix>/models/item";
import Offer from "<modulePrefix>/models/offer";
```

Second, your moduleForModel('item') should have needs: ['model:offer'].

Here's a passing a test using the provided files. (I used: ember new stackoverflow)

```
import Ember from "ember";
import { test, moduleForModel } from 'ember-qunit';
/* Import Models */
import Item from "stackoverflow/models/item";
import Offer from "stackoverflow/models/offer";

moduleForModel('item', 'Item', {
  // Item needs the offer model.
  needs: ['model:offer']
});

test('offer relationship', function() {
  /* For some reason this was necessary to prime the store. */
  /* Without this line I get the error:  
     'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'store.modelFor') */
  var model = this.subject();

  /* App.Item -> Item, App.Offer -> Offer */
  var relationships = Ember.get(Item, 'relationships');
  deepEqual(relationships.get(Offer), [
    { name: 'offer', kind: 'belongsTo' }
  ]);
});
```